# ReportViewer SubReport

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, subreport

I'm trying to do a Report with a SubReport at C# WinForms with ReportViewer. The problem is that I don't know how to do that, I searched on the web, but most of the examples were for WEB. Is there any material that could help me? What I want is a Main Report with a SubReport and at this SubReport will have another SubReport. I'm having some problems, I don't know who is going to have the parameter or where to pass the parameter, and in my subreport properties I can't find the list of subreport in my project, so i can link who is going to be my subreport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostly link u get for web useful for winform also in case of crystal report.
for ur problem [this link will helpful](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-subreports.htm)

Comment: I saw some tutorials, but they are using VS 2010 or less, and I'm using the 2013 version, and is totally diferent, many things that they do I can't do like theM, So I don't know what to do.

Comment: ohh ok.. Evan I was also use 2010 when i worked on crystal report. But i dont think there must be a huge change in crystal report mechanism of 2013. lmc once

Comment: I'm using ReportViewer, not Crystal Report, maybe I'm just having some problems, But I'm trying. Do you think that I should change to Crystal Report?

Comment: This is as per the requirements. Evan there are many other reporting tools also available. but I prefer microsoft tools for desktop applications

Comment: i find some useful link http://marcelwouters.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/showing-a-report-with-a-subreport-in-the-reportviewer-control-which-has-a-odata-service-as-datasource-in-a-wpf-application/  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing(v=vs.90).aspx  may it will useful.. All the best.

Comment: Thanks, Mihir. I research more and found things useful, I just had to create a Handle Method, now it's working, I have other problems now.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684183/multiple-subreports-with-a-subreport-passing-value-to-other